# Cannot Access Azure DB Server from Azure Website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-sql-database

I created an MVC web application using Visual Studio 2013 Web Express. I have enabled firewall rules for my machine within Azure and I can connect and remote debug my website from my local machine. I have user SQL Server Object Explorer to confirm that I am connecting to my Azure DB and that the app is functioning correctly.

However, when I deploy the application to Azure I get the following connection error. I have checked to be sure the website has a the Azure DB as a linked resource. I have used FTP to connect to the website and confirm that my connection string in my web.config is correct.

This appears to be some configuration issue within my Azure settings, but I do not know what else to check. Any advice is appreciated.

--------------- Error Received (user name and tracing id changed) --------------------------

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Login failed for user 'MyUserName'. This session has been assigned a
>   tracing ID of 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.  Provide this
>   tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed
>   for user 'MyUserName'. This session has been assigned a tracing ID of
>   'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.  Provide this tracing ID to
>   customer support when you need assistance.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> ```
> [SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'MyUserName'.
> This session has been assigned a tracing ID of 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.  Provide this tracing ID to
> ```
>
> customer support when you need assistance.]
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException
>   exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
>   +5341687
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +546
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +1693
>          System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
>   BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
>   stateObj) +69
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean
>   enlistOK) +30
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean
>   withFailover) +317
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo
>   serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions,
>   SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +892
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer
>   timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword,
>   Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +311
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +646
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +278
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +38
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +732
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +85
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1057
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +196
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +146
>          System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +16
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +94
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +110
>          System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
>          System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass2f.<UsingConnection>b__2d()
>   +73
>          System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0() +10
>          System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1
>   operation) +189
>          System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action
>   operation) +78
>          System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +229
>          System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.UsingMasterConnection(DbConnection
>   sqlConnection, Action`1 act) +376
>          System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices.GetDbProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +201
>          System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +87
>
> ```
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string.]
>    System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.GetProviderManifestToken(DbConnection
> ```
>
> connection) +271
>          System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection) +33
>
> ```
> [ProviderIncompatibleException: An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity
> ```
>
> Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner
>   exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is
>   correct.]
>          System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderServicesExtensions.GetProviderManifestTokenChecked(DbProviderServices
>   providerServices, DbConnection connection) +193
>          System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.<>c__DisplayClass1.b__0(Tuple`3
>   k) +32
>          System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.GetOrAdd(TKey
>   key, Func`2 valueFactory) +72
>          System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultManifestTokenResolver.ResolveManifestToken(DbConnection
>   connection) +180
>          System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbConnectionExtensions.GetProviderInfo(DbConnection
>   connection, DbProviderManifest& providerManifest) +56
>          System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection providerConnection) +43
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext) +62
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +123
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   +611
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +18
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
>          System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   +15
>          System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   +38
>          System.Linq.Queryable.Where(IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate) +63
>          Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.UserStore`1.FindByNameAsync(String
>   userName) +616
>          Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__d.MoveNext() +102
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52
>          Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.d__15.MoveNext() +243
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52
>          Berkemeyer.DocumentEngine.Web.Controllers.d__2.MoveNext() +244
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +93
>          System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +52
>          lambda_method(Closure , Task ) +23
>          System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.ThrowIfFaulted(Task task)
>   +33
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +68
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass34.b__33(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +16
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3c()
>   +50
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.b__3e()
>   +225
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass30.b__2f(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.b__19()
>   +26
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.b__1b(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +28
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
>          System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +36
>          System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
>          System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>          System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9651188
>          System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36213

Answer (score 14):

I figured this out on my own. Even though the web.config had the correct connection string, I found a "Connection Strings" section under the Configuration settings for my Azure website that had the wrong password. Correcting the password here fixed my problem.[image: Azure Connection Strings]

Comment: Just came here to say Thank you! Spent half an hour trying to resolve this very issue. Weird that they hide something as common as this so well. For reference, the setting in the current Azure management portal is in [website]->Configure, and quite a bit down the page. Removing the setting completely does not seem to affect the operation of the site or use of the 'correct' setting from web.config.

Comment: +50 from me. Can't explain how much you saved my metaphorical life with this.

Comment: You might want to update the answer with the equivalent operation performed in the new interface. Right now, you only show the classic one and it's going to be phased out eventually. Great info, though. Definitely.